# Calculating the angles for gear cutters

Tags: gears, machining, cutting

I need to design some custom involute gears for a project that I am working on and this is my first dive into gears.

I worked out how to calculate the size of gears by the required numbers of teeth and module.

This gear dimensions:
Module = 1mm
Teeth  = 36
Clearance = 0.1
Pitch Diameter = 72mm
Outside Diameter = 74mm
Whole Depth = 2.1mm

As you can see it's a tiny gear and I'd like to be able to make the blade to cut this gear myself.

With a standard pressure angle of 20 degrees, how would I calculate the angle of the cutting surface to make this gear profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of comments than an answer.
module = pitch circle diameter /  Number of Teeth. A gear with 1mm module and 36T would have a 36mm pitch diameter, not 72"
Also, companies such as https://us.misumi-ec.com sells 1mm module 36T gears with selectable bores sizes.